# Maven define sub-dependency for included JAR dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am working on a Java project, using maven as our dependency manager/build tool. I am currently having a problem resolving a dependency's dependency to the correct version.

The dependency in question is called jasperreports-functions-6.1.0.jar which is not hosted in a maven repo but provided in jar form.

The problem I'm having is that jasperreports-functions needs commons-lang 2.6. Inconveniently, during "compile" Maven itself builds commons-lang 2.1 to create the reduced-pom. It seems this leads to jasperreports-functions trying to use commons-lang 2.1 because it is available, but this is not valid (method undefined errors at runtime.)

I have tried adding commons-lang 2.6 as a dependency but still it seems jasperreports-functions is using the 2.1 version.

```
pom.xml snip:

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/jasperreports-functions-6.1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Using "mvn dependency:tree" I can see that no dependency requires commons-lang.

If I delete 2.1 from ".m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang" it gets recreated by maven. If I empty the folder and lock the permissions on it, then run maven again I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) on project JavaLibrary: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4 -> commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.1: Could not transfer artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:pom:2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\Lowell\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.1\commons-lang-2.1.pom.part.lock (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
```

How can I force the jar dependency to use a certain version of a sub-dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reorder the depency entries, 
first to load commons-lang then to load jasperreports  ?
**Edit:**
Maybe this should help you: [dependency:analyze-dep-mgt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607657/3102124)

Comment: Reordering does not seem to help. I have tried you second suggestion which also did not help, but I will continue looking into that.

Comment: Have you tried to add the commons-lang 2.6 lib to your local maven repository and point the pom.xml to that ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should be enough.  The newer version should override the older version AND the version you specify explicitly should override any transient dependency.  I believe Maven 2.x had problems in this area which is why I updated to Maven 3.x

I suspect the problem is somewhere else. I suggest trying to delete common-lang 2.1 and I suspect this should show you what the real problem is.

Comment: I will look into Maven 3. See my edit in the main post regarding deleting 2.1

Comment: This suggests it is the `maven-jar-plugin` which needs the commons-lang 2.1. Are you sure jasper is using it at runtime?

Comment: Yep, it looks like maven uses 2.1 to create the reduced pom. I am fairly certain Jasper is using 2.1 because I am getting an undefined method error and the method I am calling was not introduced until 2.6. EDIT: Also it turns out I was already using maven 3.3

Answer (score 0):

*Try this:* 
   **1>** Maven clean.
   **2>** Right click on project->maven -> update project configuration - > force update